# find Prime numbers up to X - complexity

Tags: java, complexity-theory, primes

this algorithm is need to make an array with size X and then each number which isnt prime toput zero in his index.. can someone please tell me what is the complexity? and why?

```
    // x is the number we want all the primes below him
    int[] p = new int[x + 1];

    // Initializes the array.
    for (int i = 2; i < p.length; i++) {
        p[i] = i;
    }

    // "Erases" the composite (non-prime) numbers.
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i++) {
        for (int j = i * 2; j < p.length; j += i) {
            p[j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

is the complexity is O(x*sqrt(x))?

Comment: Read the Wikipedia page on the Sieve of Erastothenes.

Comment: You should change the definition of j to j = i * i. Once you do, complexity is O(x log log x).

Comment: @user448810 sorry, that is incorrect. whether we start "erasing" from `j=i*i` or `j=i*2` the complexity is the same, *on random-access aggregates with `O(1)` update*, which I assume Java arrays are.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the following code, the time complexity is **O(x √x)**.

```
int[] p = new int[x];
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    p[i] = i+1;
}
for (int i = 4; i <= p.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i) ; j += 1) {
        if(i%j==0) {
            p[i-1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```